# Build cpp application

Tags: c++, gcc, linker

I have a list of files (cpp, h, and also child-folders inside with cpp/h too).

I'm not sure how to build it correctly because it doesn't have any makefile or smth like that (pure c++-files). So I decided to "catch" the right `gcc` arguments to build it.

```
g++ *.cpp `wx-config --libs` `wx-config --cxxflags` -lGL -lglut -lfkr-skeletal2d
```

Now I have that line. Here is the list of files:

```
$ ls -p
AnimationEditor/  Core-Code/  GLRender.cpp  GLSprite.cpp  Icons/         LGPLv3.txt      MainWindow.h  PlayBar.h  PopUp.h       TimeLine.h
BoneEditor/       daten/      GLRender.h    GLSprite.h    LGPLv3_de.txt  MainWindow.cpp  PlayBar.cpp   PopUp.cpp  TimeLine.cpp  wxWidgets_Addons/
```

There is files in directory `Core-Code`:

```
AnimationManager.cpp  AnimationManager.h  SkeletalManager.cpp  SkeletalManager.h  TextureManager.cpp  TextureManager.h
```

When I use that gcc-line I get a lot of linker errors:

```
undefined reference to `CSkeletalManager::***
undefined reference to `CAnimationManager::***
```

Maybe, I have to specify somehow the files from `Core-Code`. I can't understand the problem.

Comment: Yes, you do have to specify the files, just as a try can you copy those files to the same folder as others and try the compilation again, if only those are missing you may get a clean compile and linking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *best* thing to do would be to put in a little effort and actually create a set of Makefiles; a top-level one, and child Makefiles for the subdirectories. But if you want to use your same approach of just creating a command line, start by replacing your '*.cpp' with `find . -name '*.cpp'` so that it includes all the `*.cpp` files. I think after that you'll have problems finding `*.hpp` files, so you'll need to add some `-I` options to tell `g++` where to look for the headers.

So something like

```
g++ `find . -name '*.cpp'` -IAnimationEditor -IBoneEdiror -ICore-Code `wx-config --libs` `wx-config --cxxflags` -lGL -lglut -lfkr-skeletal2d
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd add also: `Core-Code/*.cpp` to the command line.